# Unable to read/consume message from ActiveMQ Queue in WSO2

Tags: api, proxy, wso2, activemq-classic

I am trying to read message from activeMQ Queue. It is dequeuing at ActiveMQ but I am unable to read it at backend. Can anyone guide how to read/print the data on my Local Machine ?

Following is the code:

```
<proxy name="Listen_Queue" startOnLoad="true" transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="MSG" value="Receiving messages from Queue" />
        </log>
        <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        <drop />
    </inSequence>
    <faultSequence />
</target>
<parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">WajihsCheck</parameter>
<parameter name="redeliveryPolicy.redeliveryDelay">2000</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">json</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueListener</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">consumer</parameter>
```

When I run the server of Wso2 MI I get this error too:

```
    Unknown error processing message org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: 
Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

[![This is my backend where I believe message should come][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teDO4.png

Amyleads would mean a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the content type parameter to below.

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/json</parameter>
```